# What is method API Testing?

Tags: api, testing

My question maybe silly, but anyone can help me ? I have a question, i read in the internet: "API testing won't concentrate on the look and feel of an application.". It is the black box testing methods, so i need to use the white box testing methods or associate 2 method ?

Comment: does this answer your question a little bit?[Check this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525814/whats-difference-between-ui-level-testing-and-api-level-testing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That phrase means that when you test API you only deal with the data that is returned from the server (unlike UI testing when it also matters how the output is rendered). When you test API you can apply black-box testing techniques sine you know what the input should be and what output you expect.

White-box testing is the technique which is to be rather applied by developers who develope the API functionality.

Comment: Thanks for you interest in my question, i can understand with API Testing method